Music simplifying modeling
I'm working on a machine learning task involving a unique dataset of piano tracks, represented as arrays with the shape (200, 10, 5000). Here, 200 is the number of tracks, 10 represents the number of notes, and 5000 corresponds to the timesteps for each song. For example, a simplified track might look like this:
[[0, 0, 0], 
 [0, 1, 0]]

This example shows a track with 2 notes over 3 timesteps. The task is to train a model to simplify these tracks. I have paired versions of the same song at higher and lower difficulty levels. By comparing them, I generate a new track where each note and timestep is classified into one of three categories:
0: No note
1: Note exists and is kept
2: Note exists but was removed

Due to the imbalanced nature of the data—where the "0" class makes up 95% of the samples (since most of the time a note is not played)—I'm using class weights in my model.
I initially tried a convolutional neural network (CNN) with 3x3 kernels and layers consisting of 16, 32, and 16 filters, along with dropout layers. While the model performed well on the "0" class, it struggled to accurately predict the "1" class and performed even worse on the "2" class.
I also experimented with combining the CNN with an LSTM (32 units), but the performance was still unsatisfactory.
Do you have any suggestions for alternative approaches or improvements to the model?
